# getting specific line from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var TheSource;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            TheSource = html;
            TheSource = TheSource.substring(1,TheSource.indexOf("</head>"));
            TheTitle = TheSource.substring(TheSource.indexOf("<title>")+7,TheSource.indexOf("</title>"));
            alert(TheSource);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i get the part of the source i need from my site and i want to get from TheSource only the lines that start with var (i have several of them)

my questions are:

1. how do i break this returned html to lines?
2. how do i get everyline and check the beginning of it?
3. how do i remove indent of the script? (cause i have several lines with the var that begin with indent

Comment: Can you try to reorganize your question?  I'm not sure I understand what you are asking or trying to do.  I'm not sure if you are wanting to do some sort of ScreenScraping function or what...  If you can provide more context that may help answer your question.

Comment: How would you define when a new line starts? Will it start after the `\n` character, or after a `<br>`? Or, since you're mentioning `var`, does it mean that a semicolon denotes the end of a line?

Comment: what i want to do is related to a intranet. we need a chrome extension that read the variables that are dynamiclly generated on page load and that is why i need to capture that part and want later to print them in the body. so i want every line to becaptured if it starts with var (plus igonring the indention at the beggining)

Comment: Hippo > yes - a line start with var and end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
var TheSource = "var abcd; abcd; abcdabcd; var abcde ; var abcdef;    \tvar abcd;\tvar;var;no var; \t no var;\nanother line;\nvar new line;";


var lines = TheSource.split(/;/); // get each line
var foundLines = new Array(); 
for (index in lines) {
    var line = lines[index];
    if (line.search(/^\s*var/)!=-1) { // look for "var" at the beginning of the string (ignoring whitespaces)
        foundLines.push(line + ";"); //add a semicolon back
    }
}

document.write(foundLines.join("<br>"));
```

Comment: what if the line that start with var has indent before the var?

Comment: The regex inside the `if` condition takes care of that, as indicated in the comment.

Comment: the indent i have is with tab... it is not spaces!

Comment: @Y.G.J: `\s` is shorthand for "whitespace character", and will match both tabs and spaces.